# What is a good java data structure for storing nested items (like cities in states)?

Tags: java, data-structures, object

I'm just getting started in Java and am looking for advice on a good way to store nested sets of data. For example, I'm interested in storing city population data that can be accessed by looking up the city in a given state. (Note: eventually, other data will be stored with each city as well, this is just the first attempt at getting started.)

The current approach I'm using is to have a StateList Object which contains a HashMap that stores State Objects via a string key (i.e. HashMap<String, State>). Each State Object contains its own HashMap of City Objects keyed off the city name (i.e. HashMap<String, City>).

A cut down version of what I've come up with looks like this:

// TestPopulation.java

```
public class TestPopulation {

  public static void main(String [] args) {

    // build the stateList Object
    StateList sl = new StateList();

    // get a test state
    State stateAl = sl.getState("AL");

    // make sure it's there.
    if(stateAl != null) {

      // add a city
      stateAl.addCity("Abbeville");

      // now grab the city
      City cityAbbevilleAl = stateAl.getCity("Abbeville");

      cityAbbevilleAl.setPopulation(2987);

      System.out.print("The city has a pop of: ");
      System.out.println(Integer.toString(cityAbbevilleAl.getPopulation()));

    }

    // otherwise, print an error
    else {
      System.out.println("That was an invalid state");
    } 
  }
}
```

// StateList.java

```
import java.util.*;

public class StateList {

  // define hash map to hold the states
  private HashMap<String, State> theStates = new HashMap<String, State>();

  // setup constructor that loads the states
  public StateList() {

    String[] stateCodes = {"AL","AK","AZ","AR","CA","CO"}; // etc...

    for (String s : stateCodes) {
      State newState = new State(s);
      theStates.put(s, newState);
    }
  }

  // define method for getting a state
  public State getState(String stateCode) {
    if(theStates.containsKey(stateCode)) {
      return theStates.get(stateCode);
    }
    else {
      return null;
    } 
  }
}
```

// State.java

```
import java.util.*;

public class State {

  // Setup the state code
  String stateCode;

  // HashMap for cities
  HashMap<String, City> cities = new HashMap<String, City>();

  // define the constructor
  public State(String newStateCode) {
    System.out.println("Creating State: " + newStateCode);
    stateCode = newStateCode;
  }

  // define the method for adding a city
  public void addCity(String newCityName) {
    City newCityObj = new City(newCityName);
    cities.put(newCityName, newCityObj); 
  }

  // define the method for getting a city
  public City getCity(String cityName) {
    if(cities.containsKey(cityName)) {
      return cities.get(cityName);
    }
    else {
      return null;
    } 
  }
}
```

// City.java

```
public class City {

  // Define the instance vars
  String cityName;
  int cityPop;

  // setup the constructor
  public City(String newCityName) {
    cityName = newCityName;
    System.out.println("Created City: " + newCityName);
  }

  public void setPopulation(int newPop) {
    cityPop = newPop;
  }

  public int getPopulation() {
    return cityPop;
  }
}
```

This is working for me, but I'm wondering if there are gotchas that I haven't run into, or if there are alternate/better ways to do the same thing.

(P.S. I know that I need to add some more error checking in, but right now, I'm focused on trying to figure out a good data structure.)

(NOTE: Edited to change setPop() and getPop() to setPopulation() and getPopulation() respectively to avoid confucsion)

Comment: Your solution looks reasonable. States _have_ cities, so it is perfectly reasonable to have City as a 0 to n attribute of a State. Beyond that either an algorithmic or performance issue might influence the solution, but it doesn't sound like it in your case.

Comment: @user432209 Inheriting what? A city is not a subclass of a State, it is a constituent member.

Comment: Right, it's not City IS-A State; it's State HAS-A City.  Composition is the proper relationship.

Comment: You could use a relational database for that

Comment: @Enrique - For this project, I won't have access to a DB, but you are right that the concept of what I'm trying to do would fit perfectly in one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you really need these kinds of aggregation (StaleList that have States, States that have Cities), then this is the correct way to implement. It may not be the most straightforward, but it is the most object oriented approach. So, for the cost of minimalism, you sure get cohesion, coupling, maintainability and all those fancy software engineering adjectives. For small projects, these characteristics should not be enforced. But for big software projects they make sense and avoid really bad code (but do not guarantee really good code).

You can also use some third-party libraries (like the one from Pangea answer) to help keeping the code simple.

See:

1: [http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cohesion_(computer_science)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cohesion_%28computer_science%29)

2: [http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coupling_(computer_science)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coupling_%28computer_science%29)

3: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintainability

Comment: Since I'm just getting started, I'm trying to lean toward the more object oriented approach. (The first crack I took at this was on the other end of the spectrum and just had a HashMap of HashMaps in a single class.) I'm still in the learn the rules before you break them part of the curve. Appreciate your confirmation that my understanding is in line with the core concepts.

Answer (score 1):

Checkout the [Multimap](http://guava-libraries.googlecode.com/svn/tags/release03/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/ArrayListMultimap.html) data structure from guava collections. This is not the complete answer to your solution but will simplify to certain level. But the beauty is that now you can use [MapMaker](http://guava-libraries.googlecode.com/svn/tags/release03/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/MapMaker.html) to cache your "population queries" against the city.

```
Multimap<String, City> stateToCities = ArrayListMultimap.create();

stateToCities.put("GA",new City("Atlanta",100000));
stateToCities.put("GA",new City("Cumming",50000));
```

Comment: Thanks. I'll look into that. If I'm reading the docs correctly, this means that there won't be an object at the "State" level, just a key. While that would cover me right now, I have a feeling I'll need the objects at that level in the future. I'm still bookmarking Multimap because I know of cases where it will work perfectly.

Comment: You can keep the State object as is and can still use it as key by overriding equals() to check equality against 2 char state abbreviation

Comment: I'm only a couple weeks into Java and haven't gotten into overriding methods yet. (I know you can and see how to do it, but haven't given it a shot yet.) I'm going to stick with the Object tree for now and swing back and look at this when I have a little better grasp on how everything ties together.

Answer (score 0):

I would consider using one class to manage a list `States` containing member variables of City and population in two-dimensional arrays.

Other thoughts:
`cityAbbevilleAl` is not checked against `null`.
At first, I misread `getPop` as a pop method and not population.

Comment: I've added a note into the original post, I'm going to need more than just the population in the City eventually. So, I think that points to the hashMap for storing each as an object. -- I'll be adding more error checking as I move forward (e.g. the null check for City Objects), but am just getting started at this point. Also, I've updated getPop() and setPop() to getPopulation() and setPopulation() for clarity. Thanks for pointing out the confusion on that.

Answer (score 0):

Spell out "population".  Key strokes are cheap.  You've already confused one responser here; it's likely that others won't get it at first, either.

Can population be negative?  If not, I'd check that in your contract for setPopulation().

Comment: negative check is the best use case for assert keyword

Comment: I've updated the original post to spell out the full word. Agree that makes it easier. I've got more checking to do in the final version and will add in a negative check. Wanted to make sure I had the core structure down before I put in all the verifications.